# Practical algorithm for testing whether an edge is Delaunay

Tags: ds.algorithms, cg.comp-geom, linear-programming

I have a set of vertices $V\subset\mathbb R^3$ and a set of edges $S=\{(a,b)|a,b \in V\}$. I want to know whether an edge in the set $S$ is Delaunay against the vertices in $V$.

My assumed definition of a Delaunay edge is: An edge is Delaunay, iff there exists a circumsphere of its endpoints not containing any other vertex inside it.

I would like to know practical approaches/algorithms for such Delaunay-edge test.

**UPDATE:** Answer to a question [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/19663/21170) models Delaunay-edge criteria as a linear programming feasibility problem. Concisely, it searches for a vector, scalar tuple $(v,c)$ such that for a set of vertices $P$(formed by transforming original points $(x,y,z)$ in 3D space to $(x,y,z,x^2+y^2+z^2)$ in 4D space) and endpoints of a  Delaunay edge candidate $(p_i,p_j)\in P$,

$v.p_a \geq c$

$v.p_b=c$

where $p_a\in P-\{p_i,p_j\}$ and $p_b\in\{p_i,p_j\}$

and it recommends using *ellipsoid method*, but [Wiki section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid_method#Performance) on this method describes it as numerically unstable beyond 2 dimensions. Is there any other *practical* yet numerically stable(in three dimensions) linear programming approach for performing Delaunay edge test?

P.S.: I have already asked this question on [ComputerScience SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24215/practical-algorithm-for-testing-whether-an-edge-is-delaunay) but did not receive any relevant response.

Comment: Easy special case: If $|S| = 1$ in two dimensions this takes $O(n)$ by finding the closest vertices to $S$ on either side in the circumcircle order.

Comment: Suresh: Isn't that sufficient but not necessary?  For example, all convex hull edges are Delaunay, regardless of how close points get to them on the inside.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving ah that's true. For some reason I only just saw your comment.

Comment: The answer you link to suggested ellipsoid for a very specific reason (keeping space small in a problem with many constraints) that does not apply here. For this one, standard low-dimensional LP algorithms such as Seidel's $O(d! n)$ one should work just fine. See e.g. http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d1/teaching/ss10/opt/handouts/lecture25-SeidelLinearProgramming.pdf

Comment: @DavidEppstein In your [response](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/19663/21170), I would like to know which _features_ you are referring to in the last statement "...because there may be too many higher-dimensional features.". Unfortunately, currently I don't have enough rep to comment directly there.

Comment: @DavidEppstein Actually, data points(vertices) in my problem come from a [3D scanner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_scanner) and are typically on the order of millions. So my problem is **low-dimensional** but with **many constraints**.

Comment: Low-dimensional with many constraints is not a problem. The better of the low-dimensional linear programming algorithms have time bounds like $O(d^2 n + f(d))$ for some non-polynomial function $f$; see e.g. Matoušek, Sharir, and Welzl, Algorithmica 1996. The problem raised by the other question was to achieve space substantially less than #constraints for a computation where the constraints were implicit rather than being part of the input. As for features: triangles, tetrahedra, etc.